# When I write a functional test in Ruby on Rails, I get a 403 response to a GET/POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, http-status-code-403

I am trying to create a new user via my functional test, but the user is not created. assert_no_difference('User.count') fails as a result.

Post part of test:
 post :create, :user => { :client_id => 'xxxx', :client_secret => 'yyyy', :email => 'anp@random.com', :password => 'testpass' }

I get this as output:
  1) Failure:
test_should_allow_bare_signup(UsersControllerTest)
    []:
Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <403>

2) Failure:
test_should_allow_full_signup(UsersControllerTest)
    []:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
<4> expected but was
<3>.

I feel that the test is unable to access the users_controller and hence results in a 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the action create on your users_controller requires authentication to be performed.

Which kind of authentication are you using?

The solution should be to perform an access before submitting your post.